# Confused in UIKit view hierachy 

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, hierarchy, uiwindow

I am little bit confused for unusual view hierachy present for UIWIndow.

If any one refer to apple UIKit Reference for UIWindow then UIView is the super class for UIWindow

NSObject->UIResponder->UIView->UIWindow.

But when one create a new project in XCode, there is a single MainWindows.xib and it contains the rest of views in the project.That means UIWindow is the super class for UIView.So UIWindow is child as well as Parent of UIView.Thats very confusing for any one.

So can any one have the clear idea related to this.

Comment: ‘Parent’ is an overloaded term. When talking about inheritance, a parent class is the same as a superclass, so `UIView` is a parent class or a superclass of `UIWindow`. When talking about aggregation or composition, a parent class is one whose instances contain other instances, like a view (or a window) containing other views. In Cocoa, the nomenclature for this is superview (a view that contains other views) and subview (a view that’s contained in another view). Both definitions are orthogonal, independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse inheritance hierarchies with view hierarchies.

A UIView instance can have many subviews of type UIView so a UIWindow is a UIView and so it can contain other UIViews as subviews.

Look at all the other UI components like UIButton or a UILabel they are all inheriting from UIView, so you are able to add them to your view as subview.